# How to hide count from GroupedList header in office-ui-fabric?

Tags: office-ui-fabric

I simply want to achieve functionality like [Bootstrap collapsible](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/collapse/#accordion-example) using `GroupedList`.

I tried to hide header count by applying `styles` props to `GroupedList`. Here is the sample code.

```
  private _overrideStyles() {
   return {
     root: [
      "ms-customRoot",
         {
           color: "red"
          }
      ],
      headerCount: ["ms-customHeader", { display: "none" }]
     };
 }

 render() {
  return (
   <div>
   <GroupedList
      items={this._items}
      selectionMode={SelectionMode.none}
      onRenderCell={this._onRenderCell}
      styles={this.overrideStyles.bind(this)}
      groups={[
        {
          count: 3,
          key: "test-group",
          name: "Test group",
          startIndex: 0
        }
      ]}
    />
  </div>
  )
 }
```

Class "ms-customRoot" is applying to group header but "ms-customHeader" class is not applying to header count span.

Answer (score 5):

Header count could be hidden by overriding a rendering function for a header via `GroupedList.groupProps` property:

```
<GroupedList
      groupProps={{
            onRenderHeader: this.onRenderHeader
      }}
      ...    
 />
```

and then specifying `headerCount` custom style like this:

```
private onRenderHeader(headerProps:IGroupDividerProps,defaultRender:IRenderFunction<IGroupHeaderProps>) {
    const headerCountStyle:IStyle = { display: 'none' };
    return (
      <span>
          {defaultRender({...headerProps, styles: {headerCount: headerCountStyle}})}
      </span>
    );
}
```

[Here is a demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/p3wqlqpmlj) for your reference

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks